# Inserting data into database on SD card - when and how?

Tags: android, database, android-sdcard

I have read couple of links on SO regarding insertion of data into DB by creating DB on the card. One of the links mentioned has this, that writing to the card will reduce the lifespan of the card. It suggested on creating links to write data onto the card after a certain limit is reached. I want to know what is the limit for a DB in an app in Android and after that is hit, how to write into the DB on the card?

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137303/how-to-store-android-sqlite-database-in-sdcard

Comment: @SardorDushamov It does not answer my needs. I want to know the limit of android DB, if exceeded copy DB to card and write/read operations from the card.....